# UIWebView write to disk method

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I am working on a UIWebView application and obtain some information from a server in the javascript code. I wish to write the JSON text to a file in the documents directory. The beginning part of my javascript file is:

```
WW.FS = {
    init: function(animation, back, fn) {
        var me = window.ww ? ww.fs : null;

        if (me != null) {
            PL.tellNative('pl:closeMore');
        }

        if (!me || !back) {
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: WW.getBS(),
                method: 'POST',
                params: {ajax: true, source: 'Touch', ID: 'INT'},
                success: function(response) {
                    try {
                        data = JSON.parse(response.responseText); <--- want to write this to the documents directory!!
                    } catch(e) {
                        PL.indicatorOff();
                        return false;
                    }
```

I need to somehow get the variable "data" back to either the .m file from which I called the javascript file or write it to the documents directory so I can read it later. Would anyone know how to write the variable to the disk? I have been looking for a method to the data to the documents directory with no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this can help you [a link](http://mobdevelopment.wordpress.com/2012/07/28/how-to-call-an-objective-c-method-from-javascript/)!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to get data from javascript in a UIWebView back to your native code is through the UIWebViewDelegate method webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType. Basically this call lets you filter URL load calls made within your UIWebView. You override this method and return YES if the load should proceed. The trick is to embed some string in the URL that would make the URL invalid and that you know means you are trying to pass data. Here's an example:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
 NSString *requestString = [[[request URL] absoluteString] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *requestArray = [requestString componentsSeparatedByString:@":##key_val##"];

    if ([requestArray count] > 1)
    {
        //...do your custom stuff here, all the values sent from javascript are in 'requestArray'
        return NO;//abort loading since this is an invalid URL anyway
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Within your javascript add something like this:

```
function sendToApp(_key, _val)
{
    var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", _key + ":##key_val##" + _val);
    document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    iframe = null;
}
```

And so to send data from javascript to the native code you do something like this:

```
sendToApp('state', event.data);
```